# Peony Alertie pant stopped growing

Tags: growth, peonies

I planted bareroot Peony Alertie in mid-July. In the first two weeks they grew about and inch with leaves but have stopped growing since. There is no change in the height of the plant or new leaf growth. I have planted it in a large pot in my patio facing East which gets sunlight until around 11.30 am and I live in Central Pennsylvania.
I water it after checking the soil moisture by dipping my finger about every 3-4 days. There is no visible signs of damage and the leaves look healthy to my beginner eyes.
Please let me know how I can help my Peony grow better.
TIA

Comment: Peony, poppy, and Iris transplant in the Fall. They should come back to life sometime. Order more now and plant when they come in.

Answer (score 1):

Peony Alertie is an early flowering herbaceous plant; provided you are giving it sufficient water and the pot has drainage holes, its likely growth has slowed because Fall approaches. If the leaves still look healthy, then leave them as they are, but as they deteriorate further, you can just cut them down to soil level rather than waiting for the foliage to die back on its own. It will regrow in Spring next year, but if your winters are very cold, don't let the soil in the pot freeze solid because that will kill the roots.